# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. What is '.'?

Tags: python, bash, powershell, anaconda, executable

I'm trying to try out asteroid (https://github.com/asteroid-team/asteroid)'s recipes, and I followed the instructions. One of the instructions is the following.

```
. ./run.sh
```

But if I do this, I get the following error.

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I feel like this is a general issue, not an asteroid only issue, so I'm posting this question here instead of at asteroid. The other question with the same error doesn't really answer my question.
What does the '.' mean? Is it bash? Does it have anything to do with git? How do I get it to work?

Comment: Try `./run.sh` and post the output if it fails

Comment: Using ./run.sh gives the same error message as before. BTW, maybe I ought to mention it, I'm using Windows 11, if that matters somehow.

Comment: Run that command in a Linux shell.

Comment: You seem to run this code as powershell or batch-language. Both don't have a command named `.`.

Comment: I tried running this in wsl2, and it finally works.

Answer (score 3):

`.` is a builtin command of the `sh` family of shells.  It instructs the shell to read the specified file and execute its contents as shell commands in the current shell (as opposed to starting a child shell process in which to run them).

The `csh` analog is `source`, and Bash (and I think Zsh too) recognize that as an alternative name for `.`.

Nothing that you are intended to run via the `.` command makes sense except in the context of a Bourne-family shell, which apparently you are not using.

Comment: I think the last point deserves more emphasis: while other shells/command environments have equivalents of the `.` command (e.g. `source` in csh), the contents of `run.sh` are written for a Bourne-family shell (sh, bash, zsh, ksh, dash... but not csh or tcsh), and trying to execute them in some other shell or environment will not work.